# How to get my DAGs back after invalid extractor configuration upload to Airflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use Bizzflow.net ETL template within my GCP project. During work on my extractor configuration (extractor.json) I have uploaded invalid configuration into my repo. Afler running `git_pull` DAG, my extractors related DAGs were removed, including `git_pull` DAG itself. How can I repare it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very common issue. Current release of Bizzflow does not check validity of configuration during `git_pull` DAG run correctly, so when you push invalid configuration into `master` branch of your project repository and run `git_pull`, all DAGs will be removed from Airflow UI.

Fixing is easy. Just repare your broken configuration, push it into `master` branch of your project repo and run `git pull` command directly on `vm-airflow` machine. To do that just simply login into `vm-airflow` machine using

```sh
gcloud auth login
gcloud compute ssh admin@vm-airfow --project <your project id> --zone <you zone id>
```

and run `git pull` command in project repository

```sh
cd /home/admin/project
git pull
```

After 2-3mins. all you DAGs will be back.

Of course, you have to have appropriate permissions to do that. Typically this fix is for project administrator with GCP `Owner` role assigned.